# Spring tries to autowire Mockito mocks

Tags: spring

I have a spring managed application in which I like for my service layer to be mocked. So I created a Spring Application Java Config and returned a mock of the actual service.

For e.g,

```
@Bean
@Profile("resource")
public MyService mockService() {
    return mock(MyService.class)
}
```

And then the MyService goes as

```
class MyService {

   @Autowired
   private MyDao dao;
}
```

When Spring creates bean of name `"mockService"`, it also tries to Autowire `MyDao` on the mock ? This in my opinion defeats the purpose of mocking. Is this the expected behaviour, whats the workaround ?

Comment: Don't mock classes. That mock is still a `MyService` with all the annotations and class information with it. You made it a bean so it will still scan and detect the annotation.

Comment: Counter proposal: Consider not loading spring during test runs. 
Specifically, do not use the @RunWith(SpringJunit...) annotation.

You should be able to mock everything used by the class being unit tested using Mockito,
then just run actual unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for both the answers, Both of them make sense, Coding to an interface will probably solve the problem. Not using Spring for testing is not an option for me at the moment though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So bottomline, its best practice to code to interfaces rather than concrete classes particularly if you are wanting to write focused tests on specific layers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you're trying to execute an integration test, but using some mocks, doing something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, YourMockConfigurationClass.class})
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    ...
}
```

In this case, you can create a mock of your service, and tell spring that this service instance has priority:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public MyService mockService() {
    return mock(MyService.class)
}
```

Doing this, whenever Spring has to inject an unqualified MyService instance, it always chooses your mock. But it doesn't prevent Spring to create the original service.

So inside Spring context there will be two instances of `MyService`, the mock instance and the original implementation. But using `@Primary` you're telling Spring that your mock has priority.

On the other hand, in order to prevent Spring to load any mock in your environments (dev, test, etc...), you should annotate your mock configuration class either with a testing `@Profile` or a custom annotation (like `@MockBean`) and then configure your component scan strategy to not load this class (`@ComponentScan(excludeFilters=@Filter(MockBean.class))`)

Comment: Thanks, but I think in my case marking it Primary alone is not going to solve the problem. As Deinum pointed out, it will still be a class with Annotations. BTW I do have my configuration class marked with @Profile. So answer is to always code to interface rather than concrete class

Comment: Ok. I assumed you were using interfaces.